# Inserting .NET object into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We have a large application with hundreds of classes/enums, and we want to use MongoDB to store some of these.

The situation is that there is a current system whereby we binary serialize the .NET object into a field in a SQL database, then deserialize on demand.  What we want is put the object into Mongo in a way that will allow us to query the object's properties directly (ie. without having to load the object into memory, deserialize, etc.).  This is so we can start to get some analytics from the historic data without having to drastically change the code base.

My question is, is this something that easily possible? are there in built serializers in the C# driver to do this?

I'm also open to answers that propose a better way to do this if what I'm trying to do is inherently wrong.

**Update:** to be clear, what I'm trying to do is take an object that has been loaded using NHibernate, and insert it into Mongo as a Queryable object.  Ultimately, I'll want to load it back into memory at some point too.

Comment: It's documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/

Comment: I'm trying to do this without massive changes to code, and the above link looks like I need to create a ClassMap for each entity (and it's children)... is there the equivalent of the NHiberate Automap from assembly?

Comment: As you're switching to a new DB, and trying to add new features ... I'd expect some significant amount of code churn. Sorry, I'm not familiar with NHibernate's Automap. The C# driver has the Mapper functionality and attributes, and custom serialization via `IBsonSerializable` (or use the more raw/native `BsonDocument`).  If you want MongoDB to perform well, you're going to add the right indexes, map to the standard data types, etc. I'd expect it to be a reasonable amount of work.

Comment: We're not really looking for any new features in the application, simply instead of storing the data as a byte array, store it as sub object.  What I don't want to get into is adding attributes to all the members, or mapping each class individually.

Comment: The basic happy path might work for you. Did you try GetServer().Collection<T>("myCollection").Save(myWhateverClassNHibernateGaveMe) ?

Comment: Yes, i've since found that... Seems the built in serializer ignores the XmlIgnore attributes, so lots of errors... Trying to workaround that at the moment...

Comment: There is one ticket about xml: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-279.  It is slightly different though.  Adding support for the Xml attributes would be relatively trivial using the convention system (and even simpler in our next release (1.8)).  If you'd like, feel free to file a Jira for adding an XmlAttribute convention at jira.mongodb.org.  We also accept pull requests.

Comment: done... could you give me a start on how to do it using a convention?

Comment: You would simply implement IClassMapConvention and iterate over the type you are provided, adding members, ignoring members, etc... as you recognize attributes that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is basically a store of JSON documents, so if you can serialize your objects in a JSON way, you should be ok to store it in MongoDB, and I assume there are lots of JSON serializers for .NET, so should be easy to find one.

Once everything is stored as JSON in MongoDB you will be able to query it without any more tools that the ones to query the database directly.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the response, what I'm looking for some more information than this.  I'm trying to serialize an object created using NHibernate and then deserialize it.

Comment: Note that MongoDB stores documents in BSON format (see http://bsonspec.org).  While BSON is short for "Binary JSON" and convenient for serializing JSON-like data structures, it is not synonymous with JSON and MongoDB is not "a store of JSON documents".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Simple.Data.MongoDB](http://goo.gl/cFUak) a lightweight, dynamic data access .NET component for MongoDB